# Global variable isn't reusable in another function

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

In JavaScript the statement `var` declares a global variable?!
So why

```
function myFunction(){
  let var1 = varG
  console.log(var1)
}
function myOtherFunction(){
  var varG = document.all
  myFunction()
}
myOtherFunction()
```

This displays the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: varG is not defined

This also happens if `myOtherFunction` is after `myFunction`.

Comment: `var` doesn't make them global, it makes them hoisted (declared from the top of the nearest function scope). So in your example `varG` only exists in that one function, `myOtherFunction`. Declaring with `var` is only global when declaring them in global space (eg not inside a function).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has the concept of [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). For this case, the `var varG` statement only declares a `varG` variable in the `myOtherFunction()` function scope. When `myFunction()` is called, it has its own scope, which does not "inherit" or otherwise know about the scope its called from, and thus, does not know about `varG`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

var does not simply mean that variable declared is global. if you want to declare a global variable with var.Do like this

```
var varG;
function myFunction(){
  let var1 = varG
  console.log(var1)
}
function myOtherFunction(){
   varG = document.all
  myFunction()
}
myOtherFunction()
```

Comment: ok thank you very much
I understood my mistake, in fact the variables defined with var do not have a global scope but the function as a scope